# Futon shows no records and CouchDB console shows all records

Tags: couchdb

It looks like Futon (the web-based admin for CouchDB available on http://:5984/_utils ) somehow caches information about data stored in CouchDB database.

I don't actually know how and why.

If i fill up the existing database with ~ 150 000 records (via PHP script on server), Futon still shows 0 records.
If i add some records via Futon itself, Futon show them up, but still doesn't show all records.

It looks like Futon uses different storage per client.
But Creating & deleting & renaming of databases itself shows up on both sides (Futon & console).

Comment: Can you confirm that you have the **All documents** view enabled, and not e.g. a map/reduce view with zero rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not normal behavior at all. Many people use Futon every day and expect good behavior.

If you are a web developer and you you don't think it's simply the browser cache, then I suggest you investigate *exactly* what is the difference between the PHP and the browser queries. You are likely to discover a big clue. You can start by simply watching the CouchDB logs and confirming that browser and console *both* query the same db.

Next, personally I would look at the bits in the air, using tcpdump, wireshark, or Charles proxy. If possible, I like to collect data on the server, to rule out a (not) transparent proxy.

IMHO, you are 1% likely to find an obscure Futon bug and 99% likely to find a discrepancy between the queries. For example, using a different `Host` header will cause different vhost rules to apply, which can access a completely different database.

Comment: I suggest also Firebug console as a very handy tool while using Futon. Use the "Persist" option in the console panel for a complete log of Futon activity.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset the couchdb process ( couchdb -k ; couchdb -b ) and you'll see all your missing data when you open Futon again.

Please notice that the reason this fix works is not because you reset the database but because you reset Futon (if there is a command just to reset Futon please let me know and I'll test). Most probably your PHP script creates an instance similar to Futon client and they will not acknowledge each other changes (I found this is the case for at least creating databases and adding documents).

Please notice that this issue only happened to me when I put my application in a web server. When this is the case the calls from Futon appear to come from a public address while the calls from my application appear to come from 127.0.0.1 ( in /etc/couchdb/local.ini I have bind_address = 0.0.0.0 ) . When I was developing locally I never had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com) config section [proxy_buffers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffers) why [Futon](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/intro/futon.html) don't show any data.

I change my config like this:

```
proxy_buffers 4 1024k;
proxy_buffer_size 1024k;
```